# Input Only parameter in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I was recently asked if we can have an input only parameter in a method?
My immediate answer to the question was "No" but as I think on it again, I am not sure if I shared the correct information.
Also, I don't have a rational explanation to why doesn't .NET allow us having an input only parameter, something like we use while implementing Contravariance.

Comment: The term "input only" is unclear in context. [Co/Contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) deals with types (perhaps of generic parameters), but .. "input only parameter"?

Comment: Define "input only parameter".

Comment: Aren't they all "input-only" unless declared otherwise?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's how I would initially view such a question, but there is no mention of [im]mutability in the post (not that it is strictly related, but the lack of such discussion makes me believe there is a large mismatch in ideas presented).

Comment: @user2864740 I think the confusion of Kunal comes from the fact that when you pass an object if you change one of its properties the change remains beyond the context of that method.

Answer (score 3):

You can read here about [Passing Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx).

I asume that when you say "input only" you are refering to parameters passed by value.

In c# you normally pass parameters by value. When you pass an object, you are passing a "pointer" by value. So if you change what the pointer is pointing to, the variable from outside won't change. But if you change things of the object, since both "pointers" are pointing to the same object both see the changes.

Therefore you can pass everything by "value", but if you are passing objects, you would have to create a copy of it to avoid it being modified by the method you are calling.

You can see a small test example here to see what I mean.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var john = new Person() { Name = "John" };
        var tom = new Person() { Name = "Tom" };

        var person1 = john;
        var person2 = tom;

        SwapPersonsMethod1(person1, person2);
        //Person1 is still John
        Assert.AreEqual(person1, john);
        //Person2 is still Tom
        Assert.AreEqual(person2, tom);

        SwapPersonsMethod2(ref person1, ref person2);
        //Person1 is still Tom
        Assert.AreEqual(person1, tom);
        //Person2 is still John
        Assert.AreEqual(person2, john);

        UpdateName(person1, "Tomas");
        //Person1 is pointing to var tom, and its name now is Tomas.
        Assert.AreEqual(person1.Name, "Tomas");
        Assert.AreEqual(tom.Name, "Tomas");

        SwapPersonsMethod3(person1, person2, "Jonathan");
        //Person1 is still Tom
        Assert.AreEqual(person1, tom);
        //Person2 is still John
        Assert.AreEqual(person2, john);

        //John name has changed to Jonathan
        Assert.AreEqual(person2.Name, "Jonathan");
        Assert.AreEqual(john.Name, "Jonathan");
    }

    private void UpdateName(Person person, string name)
    {
        person.Name = name;
    }

    private void SwapPersonsMethod1(Person person1, Person person2)
    {
        var aux = person1;
        person1 = person2;
        person2 = aux;
    }

    private void SwapPersonsMethod2(ref Person person1, ref Person person2)
    {
        var aux = person1;
        person1 = person2;
        person2 = aux;
    }

    private void SwapPersonsMethod3(Person person1, Person person2, string name)
    {
        var aux = person1;
        person1 = person2;
        person2 = aux;
        UpdateName(person1, name);
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: It would be useful if you used your `UpdateName` inside `SwapPersonsMethod3`

Comment: @T.S. should SwapPersonsMethod3 use ref or just pass parameters by value?

Comment: Use byval but swap their names. Assert that name has changed indeed but Object didn't (because it is byval). Sorry, basically, replace  UpdateNames with SwapNames - now it is clearer

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild leap here, but it sounds like you're asking if its possible to prevent a called function from altering the contents of the parameter (as seen by the caller).

ex: To make sure Bob doesn't like to program

```
public void Run()
{
    Person Bob = New Person();
    Bob.LikesToProgram = false;
    Helper(Bob);
    Console.WriteLine("Bob likes to program = " + Bob.LikesToProgram);
    //Output: Turns out Bob likes to program!!!
}

public void Helper(Person input)
{
    input.LikesToProgram = true;
}
```

---

**The answer to your question is . . . it depends on the Parameter type!**
                            ***AND***
**You can always create an immutable type through a pattern!**

---

**Pass By Value**
This is a little clarification before stepping into passing an object's reference.
All parameters are "by value".  A copy is made and passed to the called function.  Where this gets interesting is if the parameter is not a value but instead *points* (though references would be more accurate) to the value.
Which brings us to . .  .

**Objects**
What we're doing there is [Passing a reference to an ***Object***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx).
(*"Passing the Reference by Value"* as @Servy has pointed out.)
Had we passed a primitive (which is not a reference type), changes in Helper would stay in helper . . .

**Primitives**
To get the primitive to behave like a reference type (which would be the exact opposite of what you're asking), you'd need to use the [ref keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx).

**The "Object" Exception**
Some languages allow you to **explicitly define** [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) Objects.  That is, there is direct compiler support to make immutability happen.   Please see the linked articles for examples.

In other words, if I create a Person and pass the instance to a new method, that method would in affect. receive its own copy of person!

To keep it interesting, .Net has a single *native* immutable type: String.  String inherits from Object, but when you change a string, it causes a new instance of string to be created.  Your param now points to a different instance of the object.

To be clear, there are other immutable Objects via pattern, but direct support means that you never need to write

```
public void Run()
{
    String foo = "foo";
    Helper(foo);
}

public void Helper(String input)
{
    input = new String(Foo + "Bar");
    //Or CopyTo as seen in Arrays, etc.
}
```

---

**But Can It Be Done? - YES!!!**

---

There is always a way!

1. Make all properties readonly and only allow values to be set at instantiation (via the constructor). Want to change a value? You need to create a new instance!

   If you use this strategy, it would be helpful if the object implements [iCloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx).  Why iCloneable you ask? [Deep Copy Vs Shallow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/09/49935.aspx)
2. Assuming you're writing an external library and want consumers of you're library to see your objects as immutable... (ie: I wrote it, so I can do whatever I want.  YOU on the other hand can't!)  Just do the same as #1, but utilize access modifiers more permissive than private.  ex: [Internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Hope that helps!

**Update:** @Dzyann Has provided a similar answer first (serves me right for being so verbose).  If you like my answer, be sure to give him a tick too.

Comment: "What we're doing there is Passing an Object By Reference" No, you're passing a reference by value.  That's *not* the same, despite the fact that you incorrectly equate them in the next paragraph.  .NET most certainly *does* allow you to create immutable objects (why say otherwise?), and `string` most certainly is not the only one.  Java and C# also have widely different implementations of strings.  Also immutable objects need not necessarily be clonable.  In fact, *there's no reason to, you can always just copy the reference*.  This answer is just filled with inaccuracies.

Comment: Thank you @Servy I will correct the grammar, and clarify that all params are in fact values.  I assume was leaning to heavily on the linked explanations.  As far as .Net not natively supporting Immutable types, I cannot find any immutable type that inherits from object other than String.  There is no "Immutable" keyword (or its inverse), as present in other languages.  To make a type immutable, you are basically implementing a pattern.  Again, I will clarify my language so as to not cause additional confusion.

Comment: Oh, and @Servy.  The String implementation is a bit more complex than a simple pattern (thanks to CLR tricks) to ensure an optimum implementation.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/07/19/strings-immutability-and-persistence.aspx?PageIndex=3

Comment: You consider a `char[]` with all of the characters to be not a simple pattern?  That's pretty simple in my eyes.  The string's functions to search/manipulate strings are often quite complex, but the string storage itself is very straightforward, unlike say Java in which all strings are not just a simple character array, as is discussed in the exact article you linked.  Did you read that article, as it says all of that right there.

Comment: No, `char[]` is *not* a value type.  It's an array.  All arrays are reference types.

Comment: You are correct, I misread this line: "All arrays, even if their elements are value types". Will update.  But I'm not quite clear on what you're saying.  My point was native compiler support.  ie I don't have to create a new array, copy the elements over, etc.  Please see my changes that clarify that String gets all the bells and whistles via an '=' sign.  Hit me up on chat as this is getting a bit lengthy.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39447/discussion-between-jfish222-and-servy)

Comment: You *still* state that objects are passed by reference (in addition to saying that they're passed by value; you now contradict yourself).  You still equate passing a value by reference with a reference by value.  They are not the same thing.  Equating them only makes understanding what's going on that much harder.  There is no real native support for string with respect to immutability.  There is native support for it, but the behavior you're describing doesn't require special language support.  You still say immutable object should be clonable. That's still wrong. You've fixed almost nothing.

Comment: @Servy I wasn't going to bother saying this before, but then I realized you are one of the admins (at least I am assuming that given that you name is at the top near the "Put on hold..." label). Could you find a nicer way to speak to people who don't deserve the smack down? It makes answering things on this site uncomfortable when people take the daggers out like you did unnecessarily. I'm asking for a little finesse and consideration for your fellow programmers is all.

Answer (score -1):

I think, you should stop calling things what they aren't in c#.
You can read on MSDN about `ref` and `out` keywords.
I just let you know that primitive types

```
void MyVoid(int p1)
```

passed by value - means they are copied. **Here I have to make correction:** Other types passed byVal too but as reference to an existing object.

Your code will be faster but more dangerous if you pass all parameters by reference because then you save time by NOT copying it. But again, you will need to have high coding discipline in that case.

" I don't have a rational explanation to why doesn't .NET allow us having an input only parameter" - this is exactly what .Net effectively has for primitive types passed `byval`.

Imagine how inefficient .net would be if it had to copy all object structures passed as parameters? I guess, this is why MS decided to pass object types as reference

Comment: All parameters are passed by value unless they use the `out` or `ref` keyword.  The value of that parameter simply is a reference, which is a very different thing.

Comment: True, but object types are not copied. You can't assign new object but you can chage properties of an object passed to you

Comment: That's because the object, that is passed by value, is itself a reference.  That is entirely different from the parameter being a value that is passed by reference.

Comment: so, you answered your own concern, object = reference

Comment: No, your post, as it stands, is filled with errors.  It sounds like you don't actually understand what value/reference types are, or understand how parameter passing in C# works at all, given that you think your statements and mine are anything close to the same thing.

Comment: May be you should write your answer and I will learn along with the guy who has even less understanding than myself

Comment: Well, it's entirely unclear what the OP is actually asking.  He may not be referring to the concept of pass by reference/value at all.  The other answer does correctly describe method parameter passing semantics, unlike this one.  There are also *lots* of related questions on the topic, and lots of resources all over the web about it.